# Help in mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm lousy at regex and need a .htaccess rewrite rule for a following link "/eventi/123/title-of-the-event" to "/dogadjanja/123/title-of-the-event".

Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No rewrite needed:

```
Alias /eventi /dogadjanja
```

should do the trick.

Alternatively, try

```
RewriteRule ^/eventi/(.*)$ /dogadjanja/$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: @dfilkovi maybe mod_alias is not active. In that case, try the update

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^eventi(/.*)?$ dogadjanja$1
```